# Choosing a power supply, breaker amperage and wire size for a 220V welder

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

I have a new SMAW welding machine (80-250A) and I want to use it at home. I don't know yet how to make an outlet for it. Would it be correct to plug it into an outlet in my house with a 15-amp breaker?

Comment: Have you read the user manual?

Comment: Check the nameplate on the welder, looking for the values *I1eff*, and *I1max*, or *rated primary current*. You'll also want to know the duty cycle, and whether it's a motor or nonmotor generator.

Answer (score 1):

US Power grid?

*Is it correct to plug it into a 15A circuit* is easily answered by the manual.

What is the input current listed in the manual or on the Welder dataplate?

And 220V will only come from a 15A circuit if your house has one wired (NEMA 6-15 or L6-15 Socket) to an appropriate ganged circuit breaker and the welder has that plug installed.

**DO NOT CHANGE THE PLUG ON THE WELDER!!!**

Have the appropriate circuit installed to match to what the welder expects for input voltage and current if you do not already have it available.

Given past experience, it will be 220V and a 30A or higher circuit with appropriately sized wire for current and distance to the socket and matching ganged 220V circuit breakers. Ampacity charts need to be consulted.

NEMA power sockets to help identify what your SMAW welder is expecting for input current.

[image]

**NOTE:** While the NEMA 6-15 and NEMA 6-30 look similar, the 30A plug is larger in diameter.

Answer (score 1):

A 250A (output) welder will almost certainly have a 50A/240V (NEMA 6-50) plug on it. DO NOT change this or alter it to fit anything else.

No, no way in the world can you use this welder on a standard 15 or 20 amp 120V receptacle/circuit.

PLEASE just call an electrician (or two) and get a quote on having the proper circuit and receptacle installed.